# Could not retrieve endpoint ranges: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, bulkloader

I am tyring to load sstables to cassandra using sstableloader utility. But I am getting the following error.

```
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not retrieve endpoint ranges: 
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader$ExternalClient.init(BulkLoader.java:338)
    at org.apache.cassandra.io.sstable.SSTableLoader.stream(SSTableLoader.java:156)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader.main(BulkLoader.java:106)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at java.nio.Buffer.limit(Buffer.java:275)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.ByteBufferUtil.readBytes(ByteBufferUtil.java:543)
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.CollectionSerializer.readValue(CollectionSerializer.java:124)
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MapSerializer.deserializeForNativeProtocol(MapSerializer.java:101)
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.MapSerializer.deserializeForNativeProtocol(MapSerializer.java:30)
    at org.apache.cassandra.serializers.CollectionSerializer.deserialize(CollectionSerializer.java:50)
    at org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.AbstractType.compose(AbstractType.java:68)
    at org.apache.cassandra.cql3.UntypedResultSet$Row.getMap(UntypedResultSet.java:287)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.fromSchemaNoTriggers(CFMetaData.java:1824)
    at org.apache.cassandra.config.CFMetaData.fromThriftCqlRow(CFMetaData.java:1117)
    at org.apache.cassandra.tools.BulkLoader$ExternalClient.init(BulkLoader.java:330)
    ... 2 mor
```

the command I am using to load the sstable is

```
$bin/sstableloader -d nodename -u username -pw password path/to/sstable/keyspacename/tablename
```

this was working a few days back .I am not sure whats changed and how to debug it ? 
I am using datastax. 
I am loading the sstable from the same node which is in the cluster.i.e my source and destination node are same.
Has someone seen this error before ?
Cassandra version : 2.1 
Any Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this problem again, so debugged it a little for the root cause. The problem is if at any time you have altered your cassandra table by dropping some column. it triggers a bug for sstableLoader. That why dropping the table and creating it again works.

Comment: Did you find/file a Cassandra JIRA for this?

Comment: Yes I did. Here is the link.https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-11572, Looks like it will be fixed in cassandra 2.1.13

Answer (score 1):

The exception in the stack trace comes from this piece of code:

```
    if (version >= Server.VERSION_3)
    {
        int size = input.getInt();
        if (size < 0)
            return null;

        return ByteBufferUtil.readBytes(input, size); // HERE !
    }
```

I'm wondering if you're loading sstables that have been generated by a Cassandra 2.1 or an older version .... Because the issue seems to be at the byte-encoding level.

There is also a possibility that your SSTables are corrupted.

How did you get those sstables ? From a copy of another Cassandra instance ? Generated by CQLSSTableWriter ?

Comment: I generated these using CQLSSTableWriter .

Comment: Finally solved it. Somehow my old keyspace was no accepting the sstable loader. I created a new one and it worked.